# regarding playing video in android stimulator

Tags: android

I want to build an application which involves playing videos on android stimulator.Has anyone implemented it before?.Can he tell me how to play videos in android stimulator.....

Comment: sandy whats your email id...I want to contact you personally.....

Comment: how can i accept answers that i have got EboMike??

Answer (score 0):

You can find the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425502/how-to-display-video-in-the-android-emulator-from-remote-url).