# No callback for startActivityForResult in case of MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_VIDEO_CAMERA

Tags: android, android-camera-intent, android-video-record

The case is when user selects camera, he has the flexibility to either capture image or record video and the user shall be able to show the same in one's app.

For this case, `MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_VIDEO_CAMERA` intent is used but no callback comes in either case of capturing image or recording video.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_VIDEO_CAMERA);
startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO_CAMERA);
```

For getting result, code used as follows:-

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            return;
        }

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == VIDEO_CAMERA) {
                   Uri uri = data.getData();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure? Have you debugged it? Have you tried with _Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS_ too ?

Comment: No, but will it help with capturing image and recording video both?

Comment: Yes. It will !!

Comment: Can you help me with some code for this?

Comment: I can't code right now. But later i may be

Comment: Meanwhile, I try to do it on my own. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Not an issue...

Comment: 'No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.extra.INITIAL_INTENTS }' this error comes up while using this intent.

Comment: How do you manage that ?

Comment: @Surbi You could added two intents for image and video

Comment: @Piyush I tried adding two intents but it didnot work for me.

Comment: Share snippet code so i can check @Surbhi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201361/discussion-between-surbhi-and-piyush).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution and it is as follows:-

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(takePictureIntent, "Capture Image or Video");
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[]{takeVideoIntent});
startActivityForResult(chooserIntent,VIDEO_CAMERA);
```

And finally receives the callback in `onActivityResult` and I got the `uri` in this way:-

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            return;
        }

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == VIDEO_CAMERA) {
                    Uri uri;
                    if (data == null || data.getData() == null) {
                        Bitmap bitmap (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
                        // TODO:Get uri from bitmap for image
                            uri = getImageUri(context, bitmap);
                    } else {
                        //Get uri for video
                        uri = data.getData();
                    }   


            }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To start the camera and get the result back in `onActivityResult()`, you should create an Intent with `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

Similarly, to capture a video, use `MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`

Comment: I wanted to do it in a single intent, if that is possible.

Comment: Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46238195/2068732

Comment: I have that example before and tried doing that but it shows error. But I eventually came across an example using same logic but a different way and that worked for me.

Comment: That's good. You initial question though is how to get a result back from camera, and I gave you an answer. Please consider accepting it.