# Opening pdf file Error: This file could not be accessed Check the location or the network and try again. Android 6 Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to get file from external storage, then I have to send that file to pdf readers using intents. Previously below code was working fine but after installing **Android 6 (Marshmallow update)**, my code is not working and getting a toast message

"**This file could not be accessed Check the location or the network and try again**."

(This is due to new android runtime permissions). 
I just tried all the solutions (Content Providers etc but not working)
Any Solutions?

```
 File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "myfile.pdf");
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        Intent intentChooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Pdf Application");
        try {
            startActivity(intentChooser);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            //com.adobe.reader
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader")));
        }
```

Comment: so you've tried requesting this permission both in manifest and in runtime? `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Comment: Yes, I have used READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Permission but not working, same error

Comment: someone reported similar problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549807/cannot-open-pdf-file-in-external-app

Comment: I tried this solution but didn't work for me. I just found a solution, posted as answer. Thanks for your help and support.

Comment: Hope this link help you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422075/open-a-selected-file-image-pdf-programmatically-from-my-android-applicat/56946633#56946633

Comment: For Android 10, this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63364476/requestlegacyexternalstorage-is-not-working-in-android-11-api-30 (requires external storage permission)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just found a working solution for both previous and new Android OS:

**Step 1:**
Create a class names **SampleContentProvider**

```
import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

/**
 * Created by naveed on 7/2/16.
 */
public class SampleContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

    @Override
    public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File privateFile = new File(uri.getPath());
        return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(privateFile, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**Step2:**
Add the provider in **application** body of **manifest**:

```
<provider
        android:name=".SampleContentProvider"
        android:authorities="your_package_name"
        android:exported="true" />
```

**Step 3:**
Now finally pass the file **absolute path** to the **intent** by using **Uri**

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "myfile.pdf");
        String absoluteFilePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        String mimeType = "application/pdf";
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://"+"Your_package_name"+"/" + absoluteFilePath);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, mimeType);
        Intent intentChooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Pdf Application");
        startActivity(intentChooser);
```

I hope this will help you. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: A simpler and more robust solution would be to [use `FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html). Your provider, since it does not support the `OpenableColumns` and does not support `getType()`, will fail with some consumers of your content.

Comment: @CommonsWare I checked your solutions but I was failed, do you have simple sample app with full documentation?

Comment: "With full documentation" comes in the form of [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android). Several sample apps from that book are available that show `FileProvider` in use, such as [this one](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider), [this one](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider), and [this one](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Notifications/DownloadNotify).

Answer (score 12):

After reviewing the answers above the simplest solution is as follows.

```
    Uri pdf = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);

    Intent pdfOpenintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    pdfOpenintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    pdfOpenintent.setDataAndType(pdf, "application/pdf");

    try {
        startActivity(pdfOpenintent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        // handle no application here....
    }
```

The key is to set the both the FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP at the same time.

Make sure to have your provider declared in the ApplicationManifest.xml

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

Hers is the provider_paths file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Comment: It should be as accepted answer. "The key is to set the both the FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP at the same time." Thank you!

Comment: Its works on 7.1 but not in 7.0. when I'm trying to run in 7.0 its showing same error.

Comment: does it need to be external path? can it be internal to app? 
e.g - <files-path name="pdf_path" path="pdf/"/>

Comment: Works perfectly. Cheers.

Comment: The trick for me was adding `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks for saving my day with this helpful content

The key is to set the both the FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP at the same time

Comment: have the exact same problem as a Normal user. Any suggestion how to do it without the need of code ? (like via settings or any place directly to update settings?)

Comment: I had to add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to my manifest for an Android 10 device. Kindly note that this is just a temporary fix for transitioning to scoped storage. For more details refer documentation. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-in-production-app

Answer (score 4):

Use **`FileProvider`** (which is anyway the accepted approach since Android Nougat - otherwise you'll be getting `android.os.FileUriExposedException`)  and then don't forget to **grant permissions** to all the packages it needs:

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                                context,
                                context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), myFile);

                        Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        pdfIntent.setDataAndType(apkURI, "application/pdf");
                        pdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                        pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        grantAllUriPermissions(context, pdfIntent, apkURI);
```

Where `grantAllUriPermissions()`:

```
private void grantAllUriPermissions(Context context, Intent intent, Uri uri) {
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
            String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            context.grantUriPermission(packageName, uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Fires intents to handle files of known mime types, Code:

```
private void openFile(Uri fileUri) {

    String mimeType = mModel.getMimeType(fileUri);

    if (mimeType != null) { //we have determined a mime type and can probably handle the file.
        try {
            /*Implicit intent representing the action we want.  The system will determine is it
            can handle the request.*/
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setDataAndType(fileUri, mimeType);

            //We ask the Activity to start this intent.
            mView.getActivity().startActivity(i);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            /*If we have figured out the mime type of the file, but have no application installed
            to handle it, send the user a message.
             */
            Toast.makeText(mView.getActivity(), "The System understands this file type," +
                            "but no applications are installed to handle it.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        /*if we can't figure out the mime type of the file, let the user know.*/
        Toast.makeText(mView.getActivity(), "System doesn't know how to handle that file type!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```