# Can not read MS Word file in Android

Tags: java, android, ms-word

I want to read MS Word file in Android and get the content text, but after reading I got wrong characters. I tried to use Apache poi library, but app can`t compile because of the fact that the Apache Poi Library has more than 67k methods. Need help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buMKK.jpg)

Comment: The app can compile if you read the error message pointing you here.  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#about

Comment: refer this,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422075/open-a-selected-file-image-pdf-programmatically-from-my-android-applicat

Comment: @Vijay That question is for PDF files, not MS Word

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way IMHO is to port Apache POI library to Android. It's possible and there proof of that

Porting POI you can embed Word editing feature into your application.

Piece of code like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT); 
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///"+file.getAbsolutePath()); 
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "plain/text"); 
startActivity(intent);
```