# Android File Chooser and File Uploader

Tags: android, performance, file-upload, filechooser

What is the best way to make a file chooser (It should be able to choose any type of file) and file up loader  in android?

min target version - 14 and target version 25

Comment: http://sampleprogramz.com/android/browse.php

Comment: https://rogerkeays.com/simple-android-file-chooser

Answer (score 1):

All is build in in Android already.

Just start an intent with Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT to select any file on the device.

On newer systems you also can use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have used Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT only but how do we create a file from the Uri.?

Comment: You dont. And why would you? Just open an InputStream for the uri. Then you can read the content from it and write to an outputstream on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Hello for simple file selection you can use android default selection process.
[FileSelection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422075/open-a-selected-file-image-pdf-programmatically-from-my-android-applicat)

and the fastest for file uploading you can use retrofit [fastest File 
uploading](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: `Hello for simple file selection you can use android default selection process. FileSelection`. That does not select a file but offers a file to the OS.