# How to render pdf file directly inside UI in compose desktop application?

Tags: windows, kotlin, compose-desktop

I'm building an application using jetpack compose Desktop for windows os, I want to know how to open PDF files directly inside my own UI?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open a selected file (image, pdf, ...) programmatically from my Android Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422075/open-a-selected-file-image-pdf-programmatically-from-my-android-applicat)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you mean by "open PDF inside my app"? If you mean that you want to render the PDF directly in your own UI, I strongly doubt that there is an existing Compose for Desktop option for that. You would need to look into Swing or possibly JavaFX options that you could integrated. If by "open PDF inside my app" you mean launch a separate PDF viewer, Compose for Desktop should not change things much beyond how a normal Java Swing/JavaFX desktop app would do this.

Comment: Please include the 'compose-desktop' tag for questions pertaining to the same, specifically. Your tag says 'android-jetpack-compose', but I just noticed that in the statement you are using the word 'Desktop'. So I don't know whether the link I specified above will work for you, but I guess you should definitely check it out, maybe you get an idea about the workabouts here.