# Android - Image share intent like Androidify app

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I want to create an image share intent with the same options that appear in the Google's Androidify app:

[image]

I tested with `Intent.ACTION_SEND` and with `Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA`, and have obtained the same results but separately, and I want them to appear together, for this I tried using `Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS`:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Intent attachIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);

sendIntent.setDataAndType(getTempImageUri(), "image/jpg");
attachIntent.setDataAndType(getTempImageUri(), "image/jpg");
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(
    attachIntent, getString(R.string.share) + ":");
chooserIntent.putExtra(
    Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] { sendIntent });
startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

But the second `Intent` results appears as `Android System`:

[image] [image]

Obviously, the method used by the Androidify app is a mix of `Intent.ACTION_SEND` and `Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA`. **Anyone know how to do it?**

**Thanks for the help!**

Comment: .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE)

Comment: Where? If I add the "Alternative Category" to the first Intent it says "No apps can perform this action", if I add it to the second Intent the "Android System" options disappears, if I add it to the intentChooser the result is a "Runtime Exception". Please add more information to your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Get rid of `createChooser()` to get rid of the "Android System" option. Never put a chooser `Intent` into `ACTION_SEND` or `ACTION_ATTACH_DATA`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Why I can't use a chooser with ACTION_SEND? My goal is to create exactly the same chooser used by Google in the Androidify app. Yo know how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: "Why I can't use a chooser with ACTION_SEND?" -- oh, wait, nevermind, I misunderstood your code. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found how to do it, thanks to this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11038348/710274

This is my final code, I'm sure someone will find it useful:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Intent attachIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
sendIntent.setDataAndType(getTempImageUri(), "image/jpeg");
attachIntent.setDataAndType(getTempImageUri(), "image/jpeg");
Intent openInChooser = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share with:");

List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = pm.queryIntentActivities(attachIntent, 0);
Intent[] extraIntents = new Intent[resInfo.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < resInfo.size(); i++) {
  ResolveInfo ri = resInfo.get(i);
  String packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, ri.activityInfo.name));
  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
  intent.setDataAndType(getTempImageUri(), "image/jpeg");
  extraIntents[i] = new Intent(intent);
}

openInChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, extraIntents);
startActivity(openInChooser);
```