# Android - intent resolution rules - action and category

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to create an intent that would match the following test intent filter :

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="com.android.testApp.app.testAction"/>
   <action android:name="com.android.testApp.app.testAction_2"/>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <category android:name="com.android.testApp.app.testCategory" />
</intent-filter>
```

The intent resolution rules state that if intent doesn't contain any action, it can pass the action test, as long as the intent filter contains at least 1 action.

Also, all categories in intent must be present in the intent filter.

I created the following intent :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.addCategory("com.android.testApp.app.testCategory");
 startActivity(intent);
```

However, this intent can't pass the intent filter. Can some one point out why ?

Comment: as you have 2 action you would need something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021021/how-to-make-an-intent-with-multiple-actions

Comment: @ligi I want to test without specifying any actions in the intent. According to the rules, it should pass right ?

Comment: but your intent-filter has actions

Comment: @ligi From documentation :  if an Intent does not specify an action, it will pass the test (as long as the filter contains at least one action).

Comment: @ligi http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ActionTest

Comment: @ligi is the documentation wrong ?