# How open document pdf/docx with external app in Android

Tags: android, pdf

[image: image screehoot]

How open document pdf/docx with external app in Android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a PDF via Intent from SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530416/how-to-open-a-pdf-via-intent-from-sd-card)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code :

```
 File pdfFile = new File("File Path");
 Intent openPdf = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 openPdf.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
 fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(viewContext,com.mydomain.fileprovider, pdfFile);
 openPdf.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/pdf");
 openPdf.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(openPdf, "Select Application"));
```

**Note : You need File Provider for granting URI permissions [check this out](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider)**

Comment: I try  File pdfFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/eoffice/1.pdf"); but file canot show in pdf app
What is wrong url file ? i acces from internal storage in folder "eoffice/1.pdf"

Comment: @SekuntumRosela You need File Provider for granting URI permissions because you are sharing file path to an external application. also, u need to provide full path of file.

Comment: where i write file provider permissions ?

Comment: @SekuntumRosela check the link in the answer.

Comment: i try create file provider but pdf blank screen can't show

`<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>`

Comment: @SekuntumRosela did you create the xml file? post the logs it will help to understand.

Comment: this my file xml 

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>`

Comment: @SekuntumRosela can you post your code in question and logs?

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
//method to show file chooser
    private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Pdf"), PICK_PDF_REQUEST);
    }
```

You will get the result in onActivity result

```
//handling the image chooser activity result
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_PDF_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            filePath = data.getData();
        }
    }
```

For more info you can look into https://stackoverflow.com/a/11038348/11834065