# How to play a mp4 videos in Android through Server

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am using following code to play mp4 videos which is stored in sever.... And i am get error like this->

This Video can not be played????

---

```
Uri video = Uri.parse("http://129.0.0.....");

MediaController mediaController = null;
mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://129.0.0....")));
mVideoView.setVideoURI(video);
mVideoView.setVideoPath("http://129.0.0......");
mVideoView.requestFocus();
mVideoView.start();
```

---

Comment: Do a search first - there are dozens of questions about it with good answers.

Comment: First, StackOverflow is for programming questions, and this is not a question. Second, playing back videos on an emulator is unlikely to work, unless you have a very fast (and expensive) development machine. Please test video playback on Android hardware.

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpful to you i have used this in android 2.3.3.

```
public void videoPlayer(String path, String fileName, boolean autoplay){
//get current window information, and set format, set it up differently, if you need some special effects
getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
//the VideoView will hold the video
VideoView videoHolder = new VideoView(this);
//MediaController is the ui control howering above the video (just like in the default youtube player).
videoHolder.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
//assing a video file to the video holder
videoHolder.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(YOUR_SERVER_VIDEOFILE_URL));
//get focus, before playing the video.
videoHolder.requestFocus();
if(autoplay){
    videoHolder.start();
}

}
```

Comment: I have used above code but still i am not able to play MP4 videos Its Showing "This Video Cannot Be Played"....please help me...

Comment: Thanks for the Replay..But Is there any code which can be used to play mp4 videos in emulator...Because i don't have any real device..

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425502/how-to-display-video-in-the-android-emulator-from-remote-url

Answer (score 0):

Always pass the mp4,3gp etc video format link in URI.Try this code:

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
videoView.setMediaController(mc);
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://hermes.sprc.samsung.pl/widget/tmp/testh.3gp"));

videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.start();
```

Comment: I have used above code and its working for 3gp format videos but when i pass Mp4 video path its showing "This video cannot be played???".... please help Me........