# Displaying a video in android

Tags: android, video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display Video in the Android Emulator from Remote URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425502/how-to-display-video-in-the-android-emulator-from-remote-url)

I want to show/watch a video using a VideoView in android, my emulator only plays the sound of the video but doesnt show the video itself. Can you please help. here is the source code

VideoView vv;

```
   vv = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    vv.setVideoPath("/sdcard/documentariesandyou.mp4");
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this); 
     mediaController.setAnchorView(vv);  
    vv.setMediaController(mediaController); 
    vv.start();

}
```

}

Comment: That is emulator problem. Please search before ask. Duplicate [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1425502/1050058) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2184364/1050058)

Answer (score 1):

Testing video playback in an emulator is not a good idea. Due to performance issues you might end with the problem you mentioned.
Please try to test it in on a device first.